# Where ViewData and ViewBag reside?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag, viewdata

Note: This is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157886/where-are-viewdata-and-viewbag-stored-in-mvc) question as it does not answer the question completely.

My question is where exactly it get stored when you assign a value to `ViewData` or `ViewBag` like `TempData` resides in Session.

Both resides in `Session` too?

If not then where?

Comment: Answer in question you linked clearly states that: _This happens entirely on the server side but the idea that the data is "stored" on the server is misleading. These are transient objects which only live for the lifetime of the HTTP request._

Comment: But my question is that it reside in  session? if not there where? I am aware about the life cycle of these objects and limitations too. But where it resides that is what I am looking for. Can you answer that with more detail than the linked one ?

Comment: both reside in session.you can check this by disabling SessionStateBehavior on your controller..have a look here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/controlling-session-behavior-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

Comment: I'm not sure what "reside" means. `ViewBag` and `ViewData` are properties of `ControllerBase` class.

Comment: @AbbasGaliyakot: the article you linked has nothing to do with ViewBag. It only shows that `Session["test"]` and `TempData["test"]` throws exceptions after session is disabled.

Comment: @Jojo: by reside I mean to say does any variable memory created  for the same? Or internally it also get stored/preserved in Session?

Comment: The viewbag and viewdata, being properties of the controller, are stored on the heap as reference types are in .net.  They aren't persisted in the session, they passed from controller to viewpage . When the request ends, so the controller is disposed and the memory addresses marked for garbage collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @SlickSim mentioned in comment, they are stored on the heap as reference types are in .net.

`ViewBag` is of type `dynamic` but, is internally an `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject()`

It is declared like this:

```
dynamic ViewBag = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
```

which is why you can do :

```
ViewBag.Foo = "Bar";
```

**Inheritance Hierarchy:**

```
System.Object    
    System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject
```

For more info on [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

Please go through [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76153/Six-important-NET-concepts-Stack-heap-value-types) article on Value type, reference type, heap and stack on codeproject that may help you to understand where both ViewData and Viewbag reside.

I hope it helps!